# Terraform Regex: How to validate IPv4 or private CIDR as per the RFC1918?

Tags: regex, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, ipv4, rfc

How can I validate a CIDR (private IP addresses) range to fall within any of the defined range in RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918?

```
3. Private Address Space

   The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) has reserved the
   following three blocks of the IP address space for private internets:

     10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
     172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
     192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

**Context**: The issue with AWS or any cloud provider is, they let you create VPC with any CIDR you wish, they're never bound to these above-mentioned ranges.

For example, you even can create a VPC having CIDR: `169.0.0.0.0/16` which is weird.

We had an issue and spent several hours resolving the issue of integrating one newly created VPC with Cisco VPN. A DevOps engineer has created VPC with CIDR: `172.42.0.0/16`. After spending several hours we got to know that VPN will not work if the VPC CIDR does not belong to `172.16.0.0/12` as mentioned in the above-mentioned RFC (which means that CIDR range from `172.16.0.0/16` to `172.31.0.0/16` is only supported).

Let's stick to this CIDR range only: `172.16.0.0/12`. The first IP can be `172.16.0.0` and the Last IP can be `172.31.255.255`.

**What I did to solve the issue so far?**:

Played a bit with terraform inbuild function, but no luck:

```
variable "cidr_block" {
  type    = string
  validation {
    condition = (
      cidrhost(var.cidr_block, 0) >= "172.16.0.0" &&
      cidrnetmask(var.cidr_block) <= "255.240.0.0"
    )
    error_message = "Must be a valid IPv4 CIDR block address. AS per RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918."
  }
}
```

Regex:

I have created a regex here: https://regex101.com/r/iYkowj/1 which works absolutely fine to filter the ranges, but terraform does not accept it.

So the question is, how can we infuse either regex or any other function here which can validate that CIDR belongs to `172.16.0.0/12`? If it belongs outside of this range, it should display an error.

Answer (score 3):

Ok sure this sounds like fun. First, the solution:

```
variable "cidr_block" {
  type    = string
  validation {
    condition     = anytrue([can(regex("10(?:\\.(?:[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])|(?:2[0-5]?[0-9])){3}\\/", var.cidr_block)), can(regex("172\\.(?:3?[0-1])|(?:[0-2]?[0-9])(?:\\.[0-2]?[0-5]?[0-9]){2}\\/(?:1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-2])", var.cidr_block))])
    error_message = "Must be a valid IPv4 CIDR block address."
  }
}
```

Now to unpack this. First we have the `anytrue` function.

> anytrue returns true if any element in a given collection is true or "true". It also returns false if the collection is empty.

So we need this function because we have two regular expressions to validate against, and `anytrue` will validate that one or the other succeeds. The `can` function (as you presumably already know given the question content) returns `true` if no error is thrown, and `false` if an error is thrown. Combined with `anytrue`, this means that if one or the other `regex` functions succeeds in finding a match, then at least one `true` is returned as an element in the list, and then `anytrue` returns `true` and the validation succeeds. If both `regex` return an error for no matches, then both `can` return `false`, `anytrue` then also returns `false`, and then the validation fails.

As for the specific regular expressions themselves, you can consult the [regex documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/regex) to learn more about that. You can also play with this validation yourself to verify it (which I also did while I developed this solution since it is somewhat complex).

Comment: Your suggestion is in the right direction, thank you for the logic. It is giving the error for any type of CIDR (even if that is valid i.e. `172.18.0.0/16`). But I think I should be able to modify and make it workable.

Comment: @AlokNath I was using the example ranges in the question that did not contain the mask. I can update in a bit for the mask also if that is also desired. Also yes: there will be some ip addresses erroneously disallowed due to the limitations of regular expressions without making the `validation` very complex.

Comment: @AlokNath I spent more time on the regex so now it accepts the vast majority of valid inputs (probably still a few edge cases), but it is now probably difficult to read. I also began to add the mask, but it seems to me like the mask in the comment is outside the range of that in the question, so I am slightly confused. Feel free to add the mask past the `\\/` characters yourself if desired.

Comment: Thanks for retrying on this. I have updated the question and I hope I made a somewhat clear explanation this time. Let's not mess with multiple ranges, I think that is what creates the confusion. The regex should match anything between `172.16.0.0/12`along with the mask. This regex https://regex101.com/r/iYkowj/1 is working brilliantly. The last help if you can provide me, is to convert this terraform acceptable, that would be really great. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AlokNath Regex is updated for that extra portion for the mask. Please implement similarly for `10.` if desired. Also hopefully helpful tip: the closest regexp flavor for TF at that online tester would be `Golang`.

Comment: I appreciate the time you are spending to make this work, but unfortunately, that is still not working. Especially, the starting part `10(?:\\.` this part. Doest not matter if it's `10` or `172`, it simply work against any random CIDR. For example: `110.42.0.0/16` I gave this and it works, whereas, it suppose to throw error since it does not match the RegEx.

Comment: @AlokNath I observe different behavior myself with Terraform 1.1.9, so I am unsure what the delta is here.